# How to pass an array and an int trough classes and methods?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am trying to make the compiler pass the array from one of the classes to the main method. I don't know why it does not work, the code looks like this:

This is my main method -

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] board2;
        int userInput;
        playBoard = methods.createBoard();
        userInput = methods.input();



    }

}
```

And this is my methods class -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {

        //Create board method

    int[] createBoard()
    {
        int[] board = new int[7];
        int randomNum =(int) (Math.random()*5);
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            board[randomNum+i] = 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Board created");
        return board;
    }

        //Take a guess method


    int input()
        {
            int input=0;
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your guess now");
            input = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Guess entered successfully");
            return input;
        }

}
```

I am aware of that I could easily put everything in one class and even one method but i'm to practice on using classes and methods therefore I create lots of them.

Comment: you need to create class object first to call the metthod(if methods are not static) try `playBoard = new methods().createBoard();` and same for other array

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the problem by making the methods static.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new instance of `Main` and `methods` first or alternatively declare the `createBoard()` and `input()` methods static.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        methods me = new methods();
        int[] playBoard = me.createBoard();
        int userInput = me.input();
    }
}
```

Also, as per the naming convention rules for the class name it should be `Methods` instead of `methods`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the variable playBoard being used inside `Main`. Did you intend to use board2 instead. I guess you want something like below:

```
board2 = new methods().createBoard();
userInput = new methods().input();
```

You need to create an object of class `methods`, in order to access instance methods.